# Health check for Azure app service generating HTTP error 404?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, episerver, health-check

We thought it would be a good idea to enable the health check feature for our Episerver ASP.NET MVC web application in Azure. However, after doing so, the number of requests resulting in a 404 immediately rose dramatically for the path specified. The URL is internal. It works fine when browsed to. Any input on what could be the problem greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with *The URL is internal.*?

Comment: What URL is it? Do you mean "internal" as in part of the CMS? Or behind login?

Comment: What I meant with "internal URL" is only that it is not publicly accessible. It points to a start page in the CMS though.

Comment: What happens if you browse to the URL without being logged in?

Comment: Good question. Could have been a (silly) issue. But it works fine browsing to the URL in incognito mode.

Comment: Are you still seeing 404 errors for that URL, despite being able to browse to the it without being logged in?

Comment: Yes. As strange as it seems that is the case. However, I don't know for sure from where the failing requests come. I can't see the IP nor the user agent due to "GDPR". All we know is that the 404s skyrocketed after enabling the health check and that ALL requests to the specific URL fails with that result code (except my manual attempts).

Comment: I encounter the similar issue, did you managed to resolve it? @Andvik

Comment: @AruniMishra No, we eventually gave up and disabled the health check feature :/